# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments for the function 1/n(n+1)

Tags: c++

Trying to use the function (1/n(n+1)) to calculate the xNumber of a user prompted integer "n". However, it seems that this particular function gives an error when I try to run it. The functions 1/n and 1/(n+1) work just fine in the program but for some reason adding the n to multiply causes the program to not run.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,i=1,a=1,nstart;
    float xNumber=1;
    printf("Please enter a positive integer number:  ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Number\t\txNumber\n");
    printf("------\t\t----\n");


    for(i=nstart;i<=n;i++){
        xNumber +=  1/(n(n+1)) ;//(n(n+1));     
        }

    printf("%d\t\t%d\n\n",n,xNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of corrections and initializations:

```
int n,i=1,a=1,nstart=0;
```

and

```
xNumber +=  1/(n*(n+1)) ;//(n(n+1));
```

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,i=1,a=1,nstart=0;
    float xNumber=1;
    printf("Please enter a positive integer number:  ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Number\t\txNumber\n");
    printf("------\t\t----\n");


    for(i=nstart;i<=n;i++){
        xNumber +=  1/(n*(n+1)) ;//(n(n+1));
                    //^^^^^^^^^     
    }

    printf("%d\t\t%d\n\n",n,xNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`nstart` is uninitialized so this is undefined behavior. Simply initialize at declaration:

```
int n,i=1,a=1,nstart = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the reason for your error:

`n(n+1)` is valid mathematical notation, but in programming it is a function call.
Unfortunately for you, `n` is not a function.

You must write this formula like so:

```
n*(n+1)
```

Other answerers have pointed out tangential issues with your code which you must also address.